# When making a Notification non-dismissable, what's the difference between using each of these solutions?

Tags: java, android, notifications

I want to make an Android Notification non-swipable so the user can only tap on it, but can't dismiss it.

So far I've found these two solutions:

1. Setting Notification Builder .setOngoing(true)
2. Adding flag Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR to Notification object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both solutions make the notification non-dismissable, but calling `.setOngoing(true)` makes the notification an ongoing notification, by setting its flag to `Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT`.

With the flag `Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR`, the notification stays a regular one.

Ongoing notifications differ from regular notifications in the following ways:

> Ongoing notifications are sorted above the regular notifications in the notification panel
>
> Ongoing notifications do not have an 'X' close button, and are not affected by the "Clear all" button.

Answer (score 1):

They are very similar. `FLAG_NO_CLEAR` is using when the notification should not be canceled when the user clicks the Clear all button. `setOngoing` also change `Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` which has the same behavior but according to the `doc` Ongoing notifications do not have an 'X' close button and when you engage your notification with a service, The service could control your notification dismissable.